# How can I save a Google Docs image to my local hard drive?

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to save an image used in a Google Docs document to my local hard drive?

[image: Image in Google Docs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you can do it directly.

If you have to do this one time, you can **save the document on your hard drive** and then save the image.

If you have to do this operation many time, you can try the [Image Extractor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-extractor/ejihfoemkcdcfhbmbnaeabmfbkamfnng) add on for Chrome.

Comment: Presumably, you would then open the document in LibreOffice Writer or Microsoft Word and save the image from there? I know it's possible in LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: The link to the Chrome extension is broken.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it directly, but here is a workaround using Google Drive:

1. Copy the image (right click on the image and then copy)
   [image]
2. Open up a new Drawing in Google Drive
   [image]
3. Paste the image
4. Download the image in whichever format you'd like
   [image]

Comment: This method probably performs unnecessary format conversions. For example, if the original image was in JPEG format, the saved one will likely have larger file size or lower image quality.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome (and probably similarly in other browsers):

- Open Developer Tools by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Click on the "Application" tab at the top. If you can't see that tab, click on the "≫" icon to show additional tabs.
- In the left pane under "Frames", the relevant frame is probably called "top". Expand it (i.e. click on the triangle next to it in case it isn't pointing downwards yet).
- In that menu, expand "Images"
- Click on a listed image file name to see its preview on the right
- In the preview, right click → "Save image as..."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2023 using Firefox on Ubuntu, I'm able to simply select (left-click) the image in Google Docs, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, then open a local document in LibreOffice Writer and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. Now the image is shown in the LibreOffice Writer document, where I right-click it and choose `Save`, give it a filename, don't change anything on the screen about resolution, and click OK. I get the resulting image saved with no loss of quality.